# È corretto dire "sprezzando il pericolo"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request

Ho scritto la frase seguente

> L'uomo però non ha rinunciato e, *sprezzando il pericolo*, ha continuato a seguire lo squalo

ma poi ho avuto il dubbio se l'espressione "sprezzando il pericolo" fosse corretta. È così? Ho trovato alcuni esempi di uso di tale espressione su Google Books, ma sembrano essere tutti libri antichi. Se si trattasse di un'espressione in disuso, potresti suggerirmi un'alternativa?

Comment: Io ho visto l'espressione _con sprezzo del pericolo_, ma mi sembra solo in riferimento ad azioni militari della I/II guerra mondiale o con intento ironico. Però non so dire se sia caduta in disuso o semplicemente non si parli più di fatti d'armi.

Comment: Per me è perfettamente corretta, come ha detto DaG nella sua risposta "sprezzare" è transitivo e quindi ammette un complemento oggetto. Comunque *forse* effettivamente "disprezzando" suonerebbe un pò meno old-fashioned.

Comment: Io a naso direi _"a sprezzo del pericolo"_ o _"in sprezzo del pericolo"_, ma mi fa fatica controllare se siano corrette o meno.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tecnicamente è corretto, perché “[sprezzare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sprezzare1/)” è un verbo transitivo, sinonimo non più molto usato di “disprezzare”. Come accennato in un commento, oggi può far però pensare a una certa propaganda patriottica di altri tempi, dannunziana se non addirittura fascista (non che ci sia nulla di fascista nel verbo “sprezzare” in sé, ovviamente, usato da poeti e scrittori di varie epoche).

Probabilmente oggi diremmo “disprezzando il pericolo”, o in modo ancor più naturale, “ignorando il/sfidando il/incurante del pericolo” o simili.

Comment: Vedo che il Treccani afferma che "sprezzante" è molto usato come aggettivo. Sarebbe più usuale dire "sprezzante del pericolo"?

Comment: Sì, direi che “sprezzante del pericolo” suoni più naturale.